# Divide and conquer algorithm

Tags: algorithms, recursive-algorithms

Let $L_{1},L_{2},...,L_{n}$ be a sequence of numbers, and let $i, j$ be the indexes such that $1 \leq  i<j \leq n$.

I need to find the amount of numbers that satisfy $L_{i}<2 L_{j}$ with time complexity $\mathcal O\,(n \cdot log(n))$

Comment: What makes you think this is possible?

Comment: @RobArthan It seems to me that is possible and I added an answer to the question. Could you please check and confirm that the idea is correct.

Comment: An order statistic tree does this almost directly.

Comment: @RobArthan   various "sort" and "merge..." algorithms, fairly amazingly, can do such  things. For decades of my mathematical life I had no idea, until I looked a bit at some basic algorithms (mostly for cryptographic/cryptanalytic purposes).

Comment: @paulgarrett: I am fully aware that sorting can be done in $O(n)\log(n)$ time. I was asking about this particular problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the title suggests you will need to apply a divide and conquer idea. So the difficult part is the merge part. Let the following pseudo-code

```
Function solve
Input : L[1...n] a list
Output : Sorted copy of L and the number of indexes (i,j) such that i<j and L[i]<2L[j]
If n == 1:
   return L, 0
A, m := solve(L[1...n/2])
B, p := solve(L[n/2+1...n])
i := 1
j := 1
t := 0
u := 0
While(i <= len(A) and j <= len(B)):
   if A[i] < 2 * B[j]:
      i := i+1
      t := t+1
   else:
      j := j+1
      u := u+t
While(j <= len(B)):
   j := j + 1
   u := u + t
C = merge(A,B) //to have a sorted copy of L
return C, m+p+u
```

Since the merge is done in $\mathcal O(n)$ so the complexity is $\mathcal O(n\log(n))$.

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand your description of the proposed algorithm: I can't see how to put a loop around your merge step that avoids any double counting.

Comment: I edit the answer with pseudo-code. Can you check if it is correct now.

Comment: It looks promising, but it's a bit late for me, so I'll have a closer look tomorrow. For now, I can't see what $u$ is for.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that I did not use the u. In fact the u is the number that we are looking for between the two halves.

Comment: I think we should return m+p+u since $$\left\{(i,j): i<j , L_i < 2L_j\right\} = \left\{(i,j): i<j, i \le \frac n2, j \le \frac n2, L_i < 2L_j\right\} \cup \left\{i<j : i\le \frac n2, j > \frac n2, L_i < 2L_j\right\} \cup \left\{(i,j): i<j, i> \frac n2, j > \frac n2, L_i < 2L_j\right\}$$

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake, your answer is excellent! Thank you for the help!